# C# - Specifying type parameters of super-class in sub-classes?

Tags: c#, generics, inheritance, type-parameter

I am trying to do the following in C#.

```cs
public class Parent<T> where T : Parent<???>
{
  public T Prop { get; set; }
}

public class Child : Parent<Child>
{
}
```

How can I do it?

Comment: Do you just need `class Parent<T> where T : Parent<T>`?

Comment: Isnt the Definition of Parent incomplete when you are trying to use it?

Comment: @Enigmativity this is recursive, it does not work.

Comment: @PrateekShrivastava How do you suggest to refactor the code? Any workarounds?

Comment: @geeko - No, it works fine. It'll compile and allow you to define `class Child : Parent<Child>` the way you've asked for.

Comment: @Enigmativity fantastic. Is there also a way to force the subclass to pass itself as the type parameter?

Comment: @geeko - No, c# does not have this type constraint. I've mentioned it in my answer.

Comment: This is know as the [Curiously Recurring Template Pattern](https://ericlippert.com/2011/02/02/curiouser-and-curiouser/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This works fine:

```
public class Parent<T> where T : Parent<T>
{
  public T Prop { get; set; }
}

public class Child : Parent<Child>
{
}
```

Do be careful with this as c# does not enforce a true `Parent`/`Child` relationship. For example, given the above code, it is also legal for me to then do this:

```
public class Stranger : Parent<Child>
{
}
```

If you write unit tests then it's worth writing a type checker that looks for this mispattern.

Comment: Very interesting -- I've been using this pattern for a long time and I never thought that it could be misused like this. Thanks!